# Taylor series for pendulum in python

Tags: python, ode, taylor-series

I have a question from school to simulate pendulum motion based on taylor series expansion.

Angular frequency d 2 θ d t 2 = − m G R I sin ⁡ ( θ )

I am quite new to python. I know now how to simulate using Euler's method.

```
  for n in range(N_t):

  u[n+1] = u[n] + dt*v[n]

  v[n+1] = v[n] + dt*(m*g*r/I)*sin(u[n])
```

How can I simulate it using taylor expansion?
Should I run it the code only as below?

```
f′′(x0) = 2a2
```

Comment: What is f? what is a2? What is the exact task? You can not use an infinity of Taylor terms and moving too far from the expansion point gives rapidly increasing errors.

Comment: Task is to make two Taylor series approximations T1(x) and T2(x)       
 equation is d 2 θ d t 2 = − m G R I sin ⁡ ( θ ). Truncate T1(x) after the “3x-term” and T2(x) after the “5x-term”. Plot the original angular position along with Euler's equation (Euler's equation, I have managed). I have read on internet that f''(x0) can be derived by taylor series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant this from your code,

[image]

I also assume that u := θ and v := θ'.

So, the Taylor expansion of sin(x) is

[image]

and your equation is now

[image]

So, you can calculate u and v from the above equation. Or, I don't know if your teacher wanted you to calculate the integrals first and then use Taylor series.

Comment: This is what I think as well.I have made a function like the below.                                              
    def taylor(theta):
    new_theta= theta-(theta**3/(2*3))+(theta**5/(2*3*4*5))
    return -(m*g*r/I)*(new_theta), then used Euler's theorm to get second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation `u''=f(u)` you get higher order derivatives by deriving this equation by applying chain and product rule and substituting back the ODE for all second derivatives of `u`. The values of `u` and `u'` are taken from the current state vector.

```
u''' = f'(u)u'
u^{(4)} = f''(u)*u'^2 + f'(u)*u'' 
        = f''(u)*u'^2 + f'(u)*f(u)
u^{(5)} = f'''(u)*u'^3 + 3f''(u)*u'*f(u) + f'(u)^2*u'
```

There is also a systematic way using Taylor series arithmetics of automatic/algorithmic differentiation.

---

*(2022/06/29)* To solve `x''=-sin(x)` -- the constant factors become trivial by rescaling the time -- via Taylor series anywhere, reformulate this as system

```
x'=y
y'=-v
u=cos(x)  ==> u' = -v*y
v=sin(x)  ==> v' =  u*y
```

the last two via the trigonometric derivatives and the chain rule. Comparing coefficients left and right results in coupled incremental formulas for the coefficients of the Taylor series of all variables, with `x(t0)=x0, y(t0)=y0, u(t0)=cos(x0), v(t0)=sin(x0)`.

Comment: I have implemented this method myself, it is fascinating stuff! The technique seems to be virtually unknown, and is _really hard_ to search for because it contains the phrase"taylor series".  My github project contains some useful references in the README file (see "background" section): https://github.com/m4r35n357/ODE-Playground/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Some examples from the Autodiff site: https://www.autodiff.org/?module=Tools&language=C%2FC%2B%2B

Comment: @m4r35n357 : An example where I made such a construction explicit is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432062/how-solve-this-nonlinear-trigonometric-differential-equation. As far as I know, the application of this to ODE is spearheaded by Pryce/Nedyalkov, implemented in TADIFF, part of FADBAD, or its newer incarnation.

Comment: Just looked at your post.  According to the review article linked in my README the approach you showed would be called the "Differential Transform method".  It is usually used to do calculations by hand (up to evaluation of the series of course!), but uses exactly the same arithmetic rules.  The technique that I have studied and implemented is as you correctly say part of FADBAD, X-CSC and so on, but the paper that _I_ first saw was this one: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mzou/taylor/taylor.pdf  I just replaced the code generation approach with explicit functions.  Nice to talk about this!

Comment: As you say, it is quite a natural idea. But it seems that for most combining ODE and Taylor series results in Fa Di Bruno calculus as next step which is quire unwieldy. Only with some AD background comes the insight that evaluating derivatives can be done much cheaper than finding symbolic expressions for them. // Yes, what I did was to establish the computational graph manually, which is simple in the examples, so trivial as to be almost invisible. Then add the machinery for incremental Taylor coefficient evaluation.

Comment: Yes, each time I see an article describing the derivation of RK4 I wince at the bit where they use words like ". . . of course, this calculation becomes much too messy above order 4, so we will stop there"!

Comment: Oops, that should be C-XSC in my comment above!